# TestNG Listener that clears tmp folder even for an aborted run via Jenkins?

Tags: java, selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, testng

I use Java Selenium WebDriver with TestNG for running my tests.

I am calling `driver.quit()` in my final test to make sure the files created in `/tmp/` folder are deleted.

However, if there is an aborted run (via `Jenkins`), the contents in `/tmp/` folder are not deleted.

Is there a testng listener or any other way I can make sure that `tmp` folder is cleared even if the run is aborted mid-run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the issue introduced on Jenkins level (aborting action), I believe, more effective will be solve this also with Jenkins, not with TestNG Listener.

**For declarative pipeline**

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        ...
    }
    post {
        aborted {
            script {
              echo 'cleanup on abort'
              // this will clean workspace
              // cleanWs() 
              

              //or just delete 'tmp' directory
              dir ('tmp') {
                  deleteDir()
              }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Using Plugin**

https://plugins.jenkins.io/postbuild-task/

Install plugin and setup shell script execution for the job like

```
rm -rf tmp
```